# Using JQuery is() to change background-image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, background-image

Basically, I'm trying to change my page's background-image each tab I click on a different tab.  I tried using conditionals and the is() function to identify a specific tab, but I have had no luck.  Is this feasible, or am I missing something?  P.S.: I'm using jQuery 1.6.4.

HTML

```
  <body>
        <div id='pizza'>
            <div id='menu'>
                 <h1><p id='menuheading'>Menu</p></h1>
                <div class='tabbedmenu'>
                    <ul class='tabs'>
                        <li class='selected' id='pizzatab'>Pizza</li>
                        <li id='sandwichestab'>Sandwiches</li>
                        <li id='appetizerstab'>Appetizers</li>
                        <li id='saladstab'>Salads</li>
                        <li id='beveragestab'>Beverages</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class='page' id='pizzatab' style='display:block'>
                    <p>yo</p>
                </div>
                <div class='page' id='sandwichestab' style='display:none'>
                    <p>hi</p>
                </div>
                <div class='page' id='appetizerstab' style='display:none'></div>
                <div class='page' id='saladstab' style='display:none'></div>
                <div class='page' id='beveragestab' style='display:none'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tabs li').click(function () {
        if ($(this).is('#sandwichestab')) {
            $('#pizza').css('background-image', 'url(http://hoagiexpress.tripod.com/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderpictures/hoagies.jpg)');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QQ83t/1/

Comment: You have duplicate IDs, that's causing the check to fail.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QQ83t/2/

Comment: Your code looks fine but why are you adding the background image dynamically to begin with?

Comment: you can also check `this.id == 'sandwichestab'` instead of `is()`

Comment: Why not just bind the handler to `.tabs li#sandwichestab` instead of using `is()`?

Comment: also see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QQ83t/3/

Answer (score 2):

You can just do this also

```
$(this).attr('id') == 'sandwichestab'
```

in your click function

Your original code is also working fine check http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/46m5k/